# WPF handle multiple key down events in several threads

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I'm trying to make a game with two players in WPF, that are controlled with WASD/ arrow keys and can move on the game field. When a control key of first player is pressed while second player is already moving (key is down), the second player stops moving. But I'd like them to move simultaneously.

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            //Player1
            if(Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.W)) GameVM.MovePlayer("1W");
            if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.S)) GameVM.MovePlayer("1S");
            if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.A)) GameVM.MovePlayer("1A");
            if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.D)) GameVM.MovePlayer("1D");

            //Player2
            if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Up)) GameVM.MovePlayer("2W");
            if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Down)) GameVM.MovePlayer("2S");
            if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Left)) GameVM.MovePlayer("2A");
            if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Right)) GameVM.MovePlayer("2D");
            
        }
```

Comment: Just use the `Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key)` method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.keyboard.iskeydown?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Please edit question and share example code.

Comment: It kind of worked, but whenever a new key is pressed, the other player stops shortly before continuing

Comment: You would not do this in a KeyDown handler, but in something like a game loop. You were explictly asking about "several threads", which implies that you are running such loops in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with an external class from c++ (I guess it is c++) and a main class where all the threads get started from.
For 1 Player you would need 1 class or even better 1 struct which contains the states for the keys aswell as the specific buttons you want for it (changeable because of variables, maybe consider settings.txt/json to safe the new keys etc....)

Key Settings and State Class:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Media;    //Maybe you dont need some of them but you will see it in your IDE if you use them or not

namespace GAME.Settings
{
  public class Settings  //standard Values and states for the keys
  {
    internal struct SettingsPlayer1
    {
        public static Keys UPkey = Keys.A;  //List https://learn.microsoft.com/en-en/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keys?view=netcore-3.1
        public static Keys LEFTkey = Keys.A;
        public static Keys DOWNkey = Keys.S;
        public static Keys RIGHTkey = Keys.D;
    
        public static bool UP = false;      //key states
        public static bool LEFT = false;
        public static bool DOWN = false;
        public static bool RIGHT = false;
    }

    internal struct SettingsPlayer1
    {
        public static Keys UPkey = Keys.UP;
        public static Keys LEFTkey = Keys.LEFT;
        public static Keys DOWNkey = Keys.DOWN;
        public static Keys RIGHTkey = Keys.RIGHT;
    
        public static bool UP = false;      //key states
        public static bool LEFT = false;
        public static bool DOWN = false;
        public static bool RIGHT = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Get Key State class

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using GAME.Settings;

namespace GAME.Keys
{
  internal class Imports  //imports from .dll
  {
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(Keys vKey); //needed to get the async Key state
  }
  public class GetKeysPressedP1
  {
    static bool GetAsyncKeyState(Keys key) => Imports.GetAsyncKeyState(key) != 0;

    public static void Run() //this is the method which the thread will run
    {
      while (true)
      {
        Thread.Sleep(5);  //you can choose your sleep time for input delay
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(Settings.SettingsPlayer1.UPkey)) Settings.SettingsPlayer1.UP = true;
        else Settings.SettingsPlayer1.UP = false;

        if (GetAsyncKeyState(Settings.SettingsPlayer1.LEFTkey)) Settings.SettingsPlayer1.LEFT = true;
        else Settings.SettingsPlayer1.LEFT = false;

        if (GetAsyncKeyState(Settings.SettingsPlayer1.DOWNkey)) Settings.SettingsPlayer1.DOWN = true; //you could also do something in here like move to x direction etc.
        else Settings.SettingsPlayer1.DOWN = false;
        
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(Settings.SettingsPlayer1.RIGHTkey)) Settings.SettingsPlayer1.RIGHT = true;
        else Settings.SettingsPlayer1.RIGHT = false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Main Class

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using GAME.Keys;
using GAME.Settings;

namespace GAME.Main
{
    public class main //can be any class in which the thread will be created and started
    {
        public main()
        {
            public static Thread GetKeysPressedThreadP1 = new Thread(GetKeysPressedP1.Run);    //new thread
            GetKeysPressedThreadP1.Start(); //starting the new thread in the background
            
            while(true)
            {
                //Do Something with it if(GAME.Settings.SettingsPlayer1.UP){ P1.position.x++;}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As I've done this on notepad right now, I can not check if everything is right, I will check it in 20mins but maybe this will already help you

If you have questions regarding this code, just ask.
If this is all wrong or makes no sense in this specific case, feel free to edit or mark it so I can either delete or edit it because I'm not an expert in c# myself:)

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I'm using c# with MVVM... not sure if I can apply your suggestion

Comment: Well you could share some of your code and I can tell you how to use it. Its hard to understand how your game itself works because by using this you can for example start the thread from the Viewmodel, thats what I do myself and it works perfectly (it triggers some functions if I press key xyz).

Try to provide some more information and I will look into it :)


Short answer, you can apply it as you just use the GetAsyncKeyState instead of IsKeyDown, just in another thread which makes it multithreaded

Comment: Have you tried using my method inside of your ViewModel?
Because I would say it should cover your case in a good way which should be a very good option for now until you maybe find a better one.
Also it give you the ability for better testing :)